Tricopter _SIMUNET_ARDUPILOT_MISSIONPLANNER
I am working on a tricopter with SIMUNET (Ardupilot) and Mission planner and with the following default parameters. Still it is not succeeded. Please lend your advise if something is missing out.
simple setup, fcout 0 - Motor1,
fcout1 - motor2,
fcout2 - motor4
fcout6 - servo.
set COMPASS_ENABLE = 0
set EK3_SRC1_YAW = 8 (GSF).
since tricopter badly needs a compass for yaw stability
